# Codecov coverage report seems to erroneously omit __init__.py file

Tags: python, coverage.py

I'm using `coverage` and `codecov` to report coverage on my [Github project](https://github.com/spyoungtech/behave-webdriver) via my Travis CI build. However, the online reports are unexpected in that they do not match the local reports in that the root `__init__.py` file appears to be omitted.
I've reviewed the documentation for coverage.py and codecov and nothing sticks out, but I feel I may be missing something obvious.

When I run run the tests and do `coverage report` -- The results are as expected and report `89%` coverage. Note that the `behave_webdriver\__init__.py` file is included.

```
Name                                     Stmts   Miss  Cover
------------------------------------------------------------
behave_webdriver\__init__.py               206     26    87%
behave_webdriver\conditions.py              58      5    91%
behave_webdriver\steps\__init__.py           2      0   100%
behave_webdriver\steps\actions.py           79     12    85%
behave_webdriver\steps\expectations.py     173     14    92%
------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                      518     57    89%
```

This is also consistent with the XML report shown by `codecov --dump` [on the travis build](https://api.travis-ci.org/v3/job/339627926/log.txt).

However, the [online report](https://codecov.io/gh/spyoungtech/behave-webdriver/tree/master/behave_webdriver) is reporting *`91%`* coverage and appears to omit the first `__init__.py` file.

[image: codecov online report]

I expect to be able to see the `__init__.py` file here, but it appears to have been omitted in the report. Not sure why this is not showing up.

Another `__init__.py` file in the `steps` directory *does* show up as expected, so it doesn't appear to be a naming/exclusion issue.

[image: includes file of the same name]

My `.coveragerc` file is simply as follows

```
[run]
source=behave_webdriver
```

Is there a misconfiguration I'm not seeing here?

Comment: For the time being, I just switched to coveralls instead, which works fine.